# Get RightTapped GridViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I have a `GridView` where I'm storing the songs the user adds to a collection:

```
<GridView x:Name="MusicGridView" Margin="10" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Play_Song" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Songs, ElementName=thisPage, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="100" Width="100" RightTapped="Song_RightTapped">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="#FF1F4E79"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=AlbumArt.Source}" Grid.Row="0" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

When the `Grid` is right-tapped (I can't seem to set a `RightTapped` property for the actual item) I show a `PopupMenu`. However, the sender is the `Grid` itself, of course, and I can't find a way to get the actual `GridViewItem` without doing what seem like really weird workarounds. Getting the selected item of the `GridView` isn't an option, since selection isn't enabled on it. Is there an easy way to get the item as a `GridViewItem`?

Comment: Why isn't the selection enabled?

Comment: Because i don't want them to select the song; i just play it when it's tapped. If all else fails I'll enable selection, but definitely prefer not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get the binded object instead of the GridView.
 If that's the case you could try this.

```
private void Song_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Song song = (sender as Grid).DataContext as Song;
    // Show PopupMenu
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you need the index of the item that was right tapped instead of the DataContent, make sure that each item in the source is a unique instance, then (assuming you're bound to a `List`), use `Songs.FindIndex(x=> ReferenceEquals(x, song));`