# UWP GridView/ListView get the RightTapped Item supporting both mouse and Xbox Controller

Tags: c#, uwp

In this question [UWP: how to get the RightTapped GridView Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196009/uwp-how-to-get-the-righttapped-gridview-item) , there is a way to get the "right clicked" item in GridView (in UWP, GridView is almost the same as ListView):

```
var student = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as Student;
```

The `?.` symbol is interesting because when you right clicked **on** an item using mouse, this is OK. But when you "righttapped" an item using the Menu Button (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) or using the Menu Button on Xbox Controller, this is **NOT** ok because the value is null (actually the type of OriginalSource is GridViewItem).

Though I have found a solution:

1. use`(((GridViewItem)e.OriginalSource).Content as YOUR_ITEM_DATA_TYPE)` to handle menu button
2. use`(e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as YOUR_ITEM_DATA_TYPE` to handle mouse right click

`typeof(e.OriginalSource)` can be used with if...else... to choose which solution to use.

But is this the real best solution? Microsoft designed UWP and said it is optimized to handle mouse, keyboard, gamepad such as Xbox controller and even eye tracker seamlessly. So are there a better way to handle the "context menu" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/gamepad-and-remote-interactions#accelerator-support) action?

My target:

- left click an item → do something about itemlist[clicked index]
- right click an item → open a menu such as edit, delete → click edit →
  do something about itemlist[right clicked index]

PS: Try "Settings" in Windows 10, it works fine to "right click" an item (to pin a tile in start menu) using mouse , keyboard or Xbox Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ?. symbol is interesting because when you right clicked on an item using mouse, this is OK. But when you "righttapped" an item using the Menu Button (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) or using the Menu Button on Xbox Controller, this is NOT ok

`e.OriginalSource` is different type when you right-click or press <kbd>Menu</kbd>.

**Press <kbd>Menu</kbd>**

`e.OriginalSource` is `ListViewItem`

**Right-click**

`e.OriginalSource` is `ListViewItemPresenter`

And that is why `(ListViewItem)e.OriginalSource)` throw exception when right click listview item. But both **Content** and **DataContext** of `ListViewItemPresenter` has value.

When you press <kbd>Menu</kbd> button, the matched `e.OriginalSource` type is `ListViewItem`, and the it's `DataContext` is null.

And you could find some rules that  `ListViewItemPresenter` parent is `ListViewItem`, and you could use the following code to find `ListViewItemPresenter` parent when right-click the listview item and converter it to  `ListViewItem`.

When you click the menu button the OriginalSource is ListViewItem, and you could use it directly. I have tested the following method, it works well in right-click and menu-click model.

```
private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var orig = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

    while (orig != null && orig != MyListView)
    {
        var lv = orig as ListViewItem;
        if (lv != null)
        {
            var res1 = (lv.Content as string); //string is an example of data binding type of ListViewItem
            //This line will run only if right-tapped on an item, do something here
            break;
        }

        orig = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(orig);

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This solved all possibilities: 1. right click in the listview but not in any item will just run to the last line. 2. when right clicking using mouse or menu button or Xbox controller, do something before break;